# Linking image files in PhoneGap, Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

Am trying to display an image in my PhoneGap Project in Eclipse but for some reason, this won't work.The image is in the `www` folder and am linking to it this way,

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head><title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="header">
  <h3>Home</h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
  <img src="./www/flower.jpg"/>

  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="msg()" />
  </form>
   </div>


 <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h5>&#169; PhoneGap Tests. 2014</h5>
    </div>
    </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I have tried `<img src="./assets/www/flower.jpg"/>` and also the image path like this

```
<img src="./PhoneGapTest/assets/www/flower.jpg"/> tried removing the period,
```

and even `<img src="file:///android_asset/www/flower.jpg"/>` all with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your www folder is like a public folder for Apache server(or any other server)
so you must use direct link for img 
For example in www folder create index.html(default start for phonegap application) and in index file src of img is

> *`img src="flower.jpg"`*

So if in www you create directory  img path will be

> *`img src="img/flower.jpg"`*

Also, check you style for picture(be sure that in browser [Chrome for example] picture shows correctly)
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If the image present in the root folder i.e www, then this should work for you.

```
<img src="flower.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For android: You put your html/js project in the assets/www folder and for example the image in assets/www/img/goat.jpg.

if your html file is in assets/www/ use the follwing code

```
<img src="img/goat.jpg" alt="me during last summer vacation"/>
```

Comment: This cannot work if the image is somewhere in the assets folder. Only something like `<img src="file:///android_asset/www/flower.jpg"/>` would work.

Comment: @greenapps  www folder is like a public folder for Apache server,etc, so you can use direct link for files there. Check it first and then comment.